# Can't add github URL that I don't own, but contribute majority of code to, to list of projects on CV?

Tags: support, bug, jobs

I'm trying to add a github project to my CV, but I can't add it because it's not actually owned by my "earlz" username, but rather is branched off into its own "team". Although, right now, I am the creator of the repo and only contributor. How can I add this project to my CV?

And just for reference, my github name is Earlz, and the project I'm trying to add is this: https://github.com/megcoin/megcoin